# Use variables with OR to check true/false for another variable

Tags: javascript, variables, conditional-statements

I developed an algorithm that checks nextDay, nextMonth and nextYear (considers leap-year), with a boundary defined called weekSpan, that if it falls within it (and at a specific time defined elsewhere)... it'll perform an action . It's working right now, but I'm concerned, because my weekSpan variable is defined with OR values (e.g. weekSpan = 1 || 2 || 3;).

Considering that there's a variable called weekDay (value between 0 and 6) and I want to check if that weekDay falls within the weekSpan... I did something like this:

```
if (weekDay == weekSpan) {

  (code here)...

}
```

But... I tried to recreate the condition by doing something like this in Chrome's V8:

```
var weekSpan = 1 || 2 || 3 || 4 || 5;

var weekDay = 5;

if (weekDay == weekSpan) {

  console.log("Woooohhhh!");

}

Result: undefined.
```

I'm not sure which is the right way to check true or false with my code or simply do:

```
if (weekSpan) {

  (code here)...

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a function with an array for the values and check against.

```js
const isInWeekSpan = v => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].includes(v);

console.log(isInWeekSpan(3));
console.log(isInWeekSpan(0));
```

The pattern

```
x = 1 || 2
```

returns the first [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value 1 in combination with [logical OR `||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_OR_()). This is not an apropriate method to check a value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
You made me see an error based on a lazy/incorrect use of OR.
I tried it and it works almost everywhere. The only exception is Google script... I don't know why they feel that they have to be different, complicating everyone's lifes.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how `||` works. Try setting weekSpan to an array of possible numbers, and then checking if weekDay is in that array.

```js
var weekSpan = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var weekDay = 5;
if (weekSpan.includes(weekDay)) {
  console.log("Woooohhh!");
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Thank you!
This will definitely work almost everywhere... But I encountered a weird looking cookie monster called "google script" that will not accept '.includes'. I tried this as a work around (it works so far):
for (var i in span) {
        if (span[i] == w) {
          (code here)
        }
      }

That use of FOR... I've used it like that in Python and I have no idea why it works in Google scrip, since javascript uses for (e.g. var i=0; i < span.length; i++).

Will this be a good replacement for '.includes' or do you see any potential errors in it?

Comment: @Abak `i in span` doesn't do what you think it does. Using `in` like that will give you bugs because `0 in weekSpan` will resolve as true. Instead, you should use `if (weekSpan.indexOf(weekDay) > 1) { console.log("Wooh!");}`

Comment: That's definitely the best way! It was so clever!
One thing that I didn't understand about the possible bugs was: 0 in weekSpan will resolve as true.

Comment: Did you mean that when the value of the weekDay is 0, then it will always return as true?

So... I tested this:

var span = [1, 2, 3, 4];


var w = 0;


for (var i in span) {

 if (span[i] == w) {

  console.log('Woohhh!');

 }

}

Result: undefined

Comment: oh sorry I misread your comment; didnt see the `w`. yeah, that should work. Sorry!